# Proof that covariance matrix is positive semi-definite (and not positive definite)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, covariance, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

The covariance matrix is given 
$$
\Sigma_{\textbf{XX}} = \text{cov}[\textbf{X}, \textbf{X}] = E[(\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})(\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})^\top]
$$
We want to prove that $\Sigma_{\textbf{XX}}$ is positive semi-definite. For this, we can say that if $\Sigma_{\textbf{XX}} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $\forall \textbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^n$
\begin{align}
\textbf{u}^\top \Sigma_{\textbf{XX}} \textbf{u} &=\textbf{u}^\top E[(\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})(\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})^\top]\textbf{u}\\
&= E[\textbf{u}^\top(\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})(\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})^\top\textbf{u}]\\ 
&= E[((\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})^\top\textbf{u})^\top(\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})^\top\textbf{u}]\quad \textbf{(1)}\\ 
&= E[((\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})^\top\textbf{u})^2]\ge 0 \quad \textbf{(2)}\\ 
\end{align}

Here are **my 2 questions**:

1. What is the linear algebra property allowing to go from $\textbf{(1)}$ to $\textbf{(2)}$?
2. What is the information that allows to state in the last equation that $E[((\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})^\top\textbf{u})^2]\ge 0$ and not $E[((\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})^\top\textbf{u})^2]> 0$ $\iff$ how can we state that $\Sigma_{\textbf{XX}}$ is positive semi-definite and not positive definite?

**Edit**
(thanks to John Hughes)
\begin{align}
\textbf{u}^\top \Sigma_{\textbf{XX}} \textbf{u}
&= E[\underbrace{((\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})^\top\textbf{u})^\top}_{\in \mathbb{R}}\underbrace{(\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})^\top\textbf{u}}_{\in \mathbb{R}}]\\ 
&= E[((\textbf{X} - \mu_{\textbf{X}})^\top\textbf{u})^2]\ge 0 \\ 
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at line 1 as having the form 
$$
E[s^t s],
$$
where $s = (X - \mu_X)^t u$. Now $s^t s$ is, in general, the same as $s \cdot s$, so we can say that $s^t s = \| s \|^2$ (by definition of length!). In this case, it appears that $s$ is just a number, so $s^t s$ is simple $s^2$.

For your second question, look at the number $s$: it might always be zero, in which case $s^2$ would always be zero, so the expected value would always be $0$. When you have a non-negative random variable, the expected value is also non-negative, but not necessarily positive!

Comment: Many thanks @JohnHughes. Is the edit of my question reflects your point accurately regarding the first question? Regarding the question you mean $\text{X}$ could be the zero vector?

Comment: Sure .. the everywhere zero vector is a random variable, with mean $\mu_X$ being the zero vector, so you get a covariance of zero.

Comment: many thanks @JohnHughes